# string is not getting parsed correctly from XML

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML file, ion which data is in "Portugese" language. data is getting parsed successfully but its not returnong the data as expected,
Example=> I am parsing string "Próximo GP" and it is returning me "óximo GP". Its is trimming the first two letters. same problem I am having in other strings.

What should I do. Please help.
Thanks-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. `NSXMLParser` does not guarantee that it will deliver the entire string contents of an element in one go. You are supposed to declare a mutable string to store the found characters in and append to this string when the `parser:foundCharacters:` method is called multiple times. Look at Apple's sample code, they do it like this everywhere.

Comment: You're awfully confident he's using NSXMLParser, rather than some xml parsing framework. :)

Comment: @Ole: You are absolutely right. I did the same. But I think Apple should consider about this, it has my lot of time get out of that issue. Thanks once again :-)

Comment: @Kenny: Yes I am using NSXMLParser.

Comment: @Harsh you should consider using one of the many frameworks, then. NSXMLParser is no fun. :)

Comment: @Kenny: Sure I will try them soon, thanlks for suggestion, but can u tell which are other parsers for Iphone application using Objective C?

Comment: @harsh https://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=objective-c&q=xml&repo=&langOverride=&x=2&y=13&start_value=1

Comment: @harsh i've used TouchXML and found it did everything I needed. Haven't looked at any of the million other ones.

Comment: @Kenny: Sure I will definitely learn about it, Thanks for the link. :-)